# PostgreSQL- comparing boolean values which may be null

Tags: sql, postgresql, boolean

When comparing boolean values in PostgreSQL we use the comparison operator `=`.
This is all well but when I want to check against matching NULL values what should I use?

I have used IS NOT DISTINCT FROM when comparing integers that have to match if both are NULL but is it a correct way to go when dealing with boolean values?

Comment: `distinct from` also works with booleans: `is not distinct from true`

Answer (score 1):

> I have used IS NOT DISTINCT FROM when comparing integers that have to match if both are NULL but is it a corract way to go when dealing with boolean values?

I see no reason why not. :)

`x IS NOT DISTINCT FROM y` is basically short-hand for `(x = y) OR (x IS NULL AND y IS NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `is null` clause. Like this:

```
select * from my_table where my_booleae_field is null
```

Comment: It was not the question. I don't need to get data WHERE smth is null. I need to compare argument with db value where they might be null but may be "correct" boolean values as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [coalesce](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html)

Like:

```
where coalesce(your_field, true) = true
```

Then null values and boolean true will pass the statement